# Namespace vs nesting class

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I am considering these two scenarios:

```
class StructuralCase
{
   class Structure
   {
       ...
   }
   class Material
   {
       ...
   }
   class Forces
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

and

```
namespace StructuralCase
{
   class Structure
   {
       ...
   }
   class Material
   {
       ...
   }
   class Forces
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

The thing is that inside "StructuralCase" I won't be declaring any instance variables, e.g., it will function as a "parent" for the rest of classes.

This lead me to consider converting StructuralClass to a namespace. What do you think about that? Is there any hard rule?

Comment: Are you trying to limit the visibility of the nested classes? Why are you even considering nesting?

Comment: Parent class? You mean a class with inner classes? I thought it was possible just in Java...

Comment: @nbro nested classes are valid in c# too

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Yeah, from the post, I thought it too :D

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I am creating a very simple structural analysis software. For this reason I need to keep things well organised. I like using nesting in cases where the sub-classes can be related to a "parent" class. This is better than having separate classes IMO.

Comment: @JosePerez I personally never use nested classes, and for pure organization, just use a namespace. Only nest when you *actually* have a good reason to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have are two different things.

First scenario **`class example`:**

You have an internal class with 3 nested private classes

In your second scenario **`namespace example`**:

You have 3 internal independent classes with no nesting.

If the classes should only be used within `StructuralCase` use the first example, otherwise if the classes are independent and have no relationship then the namespace is the way forward.

Comment: Simple and effective. I knew that but didn't have it into account. I will go for "namespace" since these clases doesn't relate to each other.

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia yeah, classes should be structured exactly for what the are created for, including methods with specific functionality.

So if you draw your classdiagram and contemplated what the objects should do and where they belong, this results in a clearer understanding if namespace or nesting is the way to go

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you want to use a `namespace`, if only because it enables `using` statements - otherwise you have to refer to the class by all nested classes (except inside the parent class itself, of course). Thus in case 1, outside reference would *have* to say

```
StructuralCase.Structure s = ...
```

instead of

```
using StructuralCase; 
// ...
Structure s = ...
```

Functionally the only real reason to make a nested class is

- So that the nested type has access to nonpublic members of the parent type. If this is a concern over API surface, see instead [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx)
- So that the subclass isn't accessible outside the parent class, such as a specific `struct` used for results of a specific query
- So that the child class can share some Generic Parameters from the parent class, such as factory classes which need the same generic parameters

Answer (score 5):

I would just use Namespace, because you don't all the overhead of a class.

A class has more structure, variables, and methods, and offers layers of inheritance, but if you don't need them, don't use Class.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I see you were first to answer, plus one for that, but the other answers elaborated a bit more. But this was a good first answer. Cheers!